# Оптимизация работы Angular

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, angularjs

Здравствуйте.

У меня такая проблема, я имею очень большую БД, и при открытии страницы с помощью AJAX(сайт на angular) получаю дату с трёх разных таблиц(JOIN),и это длиться ну очень долго, как ускорить вот этот процесс, есть разные идеи но не знаю что мне поможет больше.

Нужно что-то вроде [этого](https://start.me/p/ZGk8zb/page), чтобы показать всё сразу.
Структура базы: Есть 3 разные таблицы, блоки(белые квадраты), сами ссылки(в каждом блоке свои ссылки) и посещённые ссылки.

Хочу использовать более практичные варианты, если у вас есть идеи прошу поделиться :)

Заранее спасибо!

Вот код который выделяет всю информацию для показа

```
function getData($myId = 0, $moderator){
$stmtP = $this->runQuery("SELECT * FROM pages WHERE moderator=$moderator order by `order`,`last_update` desc");
$stmtP->execute();
$data['pages'] = $stmtP->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

if (is_array($data['pages'])) {
    foreach ($data['pages'] as $key => $page) {

        $page_id = $page['page_id'];
        $parent_page_id = $page['parent'];

        if ($parent_page_id > 0) {
            $parent_page = $this->getPage('page_id', $parent_page_id, $select = "*");
            $parent_page['page_id'] = $page_id;
            $page_id = $parent_page_id;
            $page = $parent_page;
            $data['pages'][$key] = $page;
        }

        $stmtT = $this->runQuery("SELECT * FROM tabs WHERE page_id=$page_id order by `col`,`order`,`tab_id` desc");
        $stmtT->execute();
        $tabs = $stmtT->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);


        if (is_array($tabs)) {
            foreach ($tabs as $tabKey => $tab) {
                $tab_id = $tab['tab_id'];
                $parent_tab_id = $tab['parent'];

                if ($parent_tab_id > 0) {
                    $parent_tab = $this->getTab('tab_id', $parent_tab_id);
                    $parent_tab['tab_id'] = $tab_id;
                    $tab_id = $parent_tab_id;
                    $tab = $parent_tab;
                }

                $tab['links'] = $this->getLinks($tab_id, $myId);

                $tabs[$tabKey] = $tab;
            }
        }
        $data['pages'][$key]['tabs'] = $tabs;
    }
}
return $data;}function getTab($field, $value, $select = "*"){$stmt = $this>runQuery("SELECT $select FROM tabs WHERE $field=:value");$stmt->execute(array(':value' => $value));
return $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);}public function getLinks($tab_id, $myId = 0, $select = '*'){

$stmt = $this->runQuery("SELECT $select FROM links 
                            left JOIN visited_links ON links.link_id=visited_links.v_link_id and u_id=$myId
                            WHERE tab_id=$tab_id order by `order`,`last_update` desc");

$stmt->execute();
return $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);}
```

Answer (score 0):

Думаю вам следует создать индексы по полям, по которым будут присоединяться таблицы. Это значительно ускорит скорость выборки из различных таблиц с использованием JOIN. Но для начала, было бы неплохо, проанализировать запросы с помощью [EXPLAIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/explain-output.html).
Почитать о индексах можно [тут](http://www.php.su/articles/?cat=phpdb&page=005)